How convert .tflite to mediaPipe
I am trying to create a llm in mobile using gemma-2b-it, but I have a problem when I try to run the llm with mediapipe.
E0000 00:00:1719161438.366071   20510 calculator_graph.cc:887] INTERNAL: CalculatorGraph::Run() failed:  Calculator::Open() for node "odml.infra.TfLitePrefillDecodeRunnerCalculator" failed: ; RET_CHECK failure (external/odml/odml/infra/genai/inference/calculators/tflite_prefill_decode_runner_calculator.cc:157) (prefill_runner_)!=(nullptr)
the step that I followed were:
trained the llm with keras.
Convert from keras to tflite.
Convert tflite to mediaPipe. (using llm_convert.ipynb)
load .task in android with mediapipe
Does Anybody know something about that error?
I want finetunning llm with keras and run in mobile device

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
